# Can a product have unlimited stock?

Tags: magento-1.9, products, quantity

another problem i've having with magento is trying to get around the fact that you have to input stock.**is there a way to allow for unlimited stock? or even the option to disregaurd the stock all together ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable it for products individually or for the whole store.

**Individual products:**
Catalog --> Manage products --> select the product --> Inventoy

set Manage Stock to no

**Store:**
System --> Configuration --> Inventory --> Product stock options

set Manage Stock to no

Comment: i've been set this option but the product not appear in frontend , the quantity of the product is 0 . any suggestion about that ?

Comment: Make sure that is the Visibility under the general tab to catalog (and search if you want), than reindex and empty the cache